# windown to linux porting: how to replace __stdcall?

Tags: c++, linux, callback

I'm porting my application from Windows to Linux.
In Windows version i've defined such callback `typedef void (__stdcall * OrdersCallback)(orders*);`. Then I implement it like this:

```
void __stdcall OrdersHandler(orders* param) {
    Processor::Instance().EnqueueFutOrderbook(param);
};
```

and I pass pointer to this handler from my application to statically linked library so library can pass data back.

But in Linux this line doesn't compile: `typedef void (__stdcall * OrdersCallback)(orders*);`. How should I update my callback declaration and implementation to make it compile in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the callback is implemened and used only in your program/lib 
(ie. no external libs will call it), then the calling convention won´t matter.
Just remove `__stdcall` everywhere

Comment: I would expect a Linux development environment with `#define __stdcall` (that is, to empty). And if not, I'd use a compile switch to make that true. No need for mass search and replace.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus that's a slightly more appropriate answer, don't suppose you know how to force the calling convention on Linux, though? That's what I'm currently stuck with and in reality is the "correct" answer to OP...